# $\lim_{p\to\infty}{\ell^p}$ and how this relates to the maximum metric.

Tags: limits, metric-spaces

If the $\ell^p$ norm metric is defined as 
$$
\ell^p=\left[\sum_{n=1}^{m}{x_{n}^p}\right]^{1/p}
$$
and the $\ell^\infty$ norm metric is defined as 
$$
\ell^\infty=\max(|x_1|,|x_2|,|x_3|...,|x_{m-1}|,|x_m|)
$$ 
Does this imply that
$$
\lim_{p\to \infty}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{m}{x_{n}^p}\right]^{1/p}=\max(|x_1|,|x_2|,|x_3|...,|x_{m-1}|,|x_m|)?
$$

Comment: In the LHS of your last equation, $p$ is a "dummy variable", i.e. you're taking a limit with respect to $p$. In the RHS, $p$ seems to be some fixed value. Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: The last equation is fixed.

Comment: @Brothersquid You seem to be double using $p$; as you've written the question, $p$ is both the power and the indexing variable. Instead perhaps you mean to take $x \in \mathbb R^m$ and consider $$\lim_{p\to\infty} \left(\sum^m_{n=1} \lvert x_n\rvert^p \right)^{1/p}.$$ Here $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ should be some fixed object; otherwise the question isn't really well posed.

Comment: Question is reformatted correctly is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The correct formula is indeed $l_p = (\sum_{n=1}^{m} |x_n|^p)^{1/p}$.

Let $|x_k|$ be the largest component of the vector$(|x_1|, ..., |x_m|)^T$. **It is $l_{\infty} = |x_k|$ as claimed in the question.**

**Proof:**

$l_p = |x_k|(\sum_{n=1}^{m}(\frac{|x_n|}{|x_k|})^p)^{1/p} = |x_k|(1 + \sum_{n=1, n\neq k}^{m}(\frac{|x_n|}{|x_k|})^p)^{1/p}.$

$lim_{p \rightarrow \infty}(1 + \sum_{n=1, n\neq k}^{m}(\frac{|x_n|}{|x_k|})^p)^{1/p} = 1$, which can be shown by sandwiching the term between 1 and $\sqrt[p]{p}$ as follows:

Since $\frac{|x_n|}{|x_k|} \leq 1 \Rightarrow  \sum_{n=1, n\neq k}^{m}(\frac{|x_n|}{|x_k|})^p$ does not increase in p.

$\Rightarrow \exists p \in N : \sum_{n=1, n\neq k}^{m}(\frac{|x_n|}{|x_k|}) < p $. $ \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1, n\neq k}^{m}(\frac{|x_n|}{|x_k|})^{2p} \leq \sum_{n=1, n\neq k}^{m}(\frac{|x_n|}{|x_k|}) < p < 2p$.

$t \geq 2p+1 \Rightarrow 1 \leq (1 + \sum_{n=1, n\neq k}^{m}(\frac{|x_n|}{|x_k|})^t)^{1/t} \leq \sqrt[t]{t}$. But $lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[t]{t} = 1$.

Comment: The assumption that $\frac{|x_n|}{|x_k|}<1$ for $n\neq k$ is not correct. You could also have equality. Thus, the sum you are referring to may remain constant (it doesn't necessarily decrease as you stated).

Comment: I repaired it by changing one sign and one word. The logic is obviously correct

Answer (score 0):

For each $i$ we have $|x_i| = (|x_i|^{p})^{1/p} \leq (\sum_{i=1}^{m} |x_i|^{p})^{1/p}$. So $\max \{|x_1|,|x_2|,...,|x_m|\} \leq (\sum_{i=1}^{m} |x_i|^{p})^{1/p}$.  Let $j$ be an index such that $|x_j| =\max \{|x_1|,|x_2|,...,|x_m|\}$. Then $(\sum_{i=1}^{m} |x_i|^{p})^{1/p} \leq (m|x_j|^{p})^{1/p} =m^{1/p} |x_j| \to |x_j| = \max \{|x_1|,|x_2|,...,|x_m|\}$. Combining the two statement just proved we see that $(\sum_{i=1}^{m} |x_i|^{p})^{1/p} \to \max \{|x_1|,|x_2|,...,|x_m|\}$